# Abstract base class manipulating variables in Python

Tags: python, abstract-class

I have two classes that share a lot of functionality and I would like to move that functionality into abstract class they will inherit from. Few of that functions manipulate instance variables in this manner:

```
def foo(bar):
    if self.ook < 5:
        self.ook = bar
```

but these local variables are created in the constructors of these secondary classes so the  abstract class does not see the variable "ook". Should I create a constructor in that abstract class and create a variable "ook" with some random value with the knowledge, that this constructor will be overwritten? Or should I somehow use properties? Thanks.

Comment: Neither. Python is a [late binding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_binding) language, so as long as the variable name exsists when the function is actually called at runtime, it will work. Doing this will also cause the method to throw exceptions if someone instantiates the abstract class rather than its children and then calls the method, which is probably a good thing (since python has no notion of actually abstract classes)

Comment: Thanks. I am using sublimetext with pylinter plugin - is there any way how to stop him from complaining about "Instance of this class has no xxx member"?